# Logstash normalise URL from JSON logs

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

I have logs in new line separated JSON like following

```
{
  "httpRequest": {
    "requestMethod": "GET",
    "requestUrl": "/foo/submit?proj=56"
  }
}
```

Now I need the url without the dynamic parts in the i.e. 1st resource (someTenant) and the query parameters to be added as a field in elasticsearch ie. the expected normalised url is

```
"requestUrl": "/{{someTenant}}/submit?{{someParams}}"
```

I already have the following filter in logstash config but not sure how to do sequence of regex operation on a specific field and add it as a new one.

```
    json{
        source => "message"
    }
```

This way I could aggregate the unique endpoints although the urls are different in logs due to variable path params and query params.

Answer (score 0):

Since this question tagged with `grok`, i will go ahead and assume you can use `grok` filters.

use `grok` filter and create a new field from `requestUrl` field, you can then use [URIPATHPARAM](https://github.com/elastic/logstash/blob/v1.4.2/patterns/grok-patterns) grok pattern to separate various components from `requestUrl` as follows,

```
grok {
  match => {"requestUrl" => "%{URIPATHPARAM:request_data}"}
}
```

this will produce following output,

```
{
  "request_data": [
    [
      "/foo/submit?proj=56"
    ]
  ],
  "URIPATH": [
    [
      "/foo/submit"
    ]
  ],
  "URIPARAM": [
    [
      "?proj=56"
    ]
  ]
}
```

Can be tested on [Grok Online Debugger](https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/)

thanks